# How to parse multiple JSON when response is nested in JAVA

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I have this response

```
[
    {\"pk\": 700, 
     \"model\": \"carsys.report\", 
     \"fields\": 
        {\"taser_stat\": false, 
         \"user\": 9, 
         \"date_reported\": 
         \"2017-09-09T16:47:22.891Z\", 
         \"car_ignition\": false, 
         \"car_id\": 4, 
         \"car_loc_stat\": false, 
         \"report_stat\": false, 
         \"car_loc\": \"Latitude: 14.549935Longitude: 121.065145https://www.google.com.ph/maps/@14.549935,121.065145,17z\", 
         \"rep_photo\": \"bear.PNG\",
         \"car_photo_stat\": false
        }
    },
     {\"pk\": 699, 
      \"model\": \"carsys.report\",
      \"fields\": 
        {\"taser_stat\": false, 
         \"user\": 9, 
         \"date_reported\": \"2017-09-09T15:41:58.237Z\", 
         \"car_ignition\": false, 
         \"car_id\": 4, 
         \"car_loc_stat\": false, 
         \"report_stat\": false, 
         \"car_loc\":
         \"Latitude: 14.549935Longitude: 121.065145https://www.google.com.ph/maps/@14.549935,121.065145,17z\", 
         \"rep_photo\": \"Capture.PNG\", 
         \"car_photo_stat\": false
        }
     }
 ]
```

All the other items I found has a main anchor like a "My Response":{...} before the main JSON object.
I'd just like to know how to handle this type of response. Like how to get the car_photo per PK. I plan on using this response for an Android App that collects all "reports"(pk) returned by the web API thru Volley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using org.json

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourJsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    int pk = jsonObject.getInt("pk");
    boolean carPhotoStat = jsonObject.getJSONObject("fields").getBoolean("car_photo_stat");

    System.out.printf("%d: %b\n", pk, carPhotoStat);
}
```

Every JSON library I know (GSON etc) are able to handle json objects just fine without explicitly naming them in arrays.